# JOLT transformation build array of objects grouping attributes in the same object

Tags: java, json, transform, jolt

I'm trying to construct an array of objects named catalogs with different combinations of input values, but can't set some attributes in the same object. This is the current progress:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "new": {
        "bc_sku_channel": {
          "*": {
            "Partner": null, //ignore if value is Partner 
            "*": {
              "#BC": "catalogs[#3].catalog",
              "@1": "catalogs[#3].channel"
            }
          }
        },
        "bc_sku_partner": {
          "*": {
            "#BC": "catalogs[].catalog", // don't know which index should be here to group these 3 attributes into the same object
            "#Partner": "catalogs[].channel", // tried #3,#2,#1,#4 but doesn't work
            "@": "catalogs[].partner"
          }
        },
        "cc_sku_channel": {
          "*": {
            "Partner": null, //ignore if value is Partner 
            "*": {
              "#CC": "catalogs[#3].catalog",
              "@1": "catalogs[#3].channel"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Input:

```json
{
  "new": {
    "bc_sku_partner": [
      "Amazon",
      "Ebay"
    ],
    "bc_sku_channel": [
      "Partner",
      "Online",
      "Store"
    ],
    "cc_sku_channel": [
      "Store"
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
 {
  "catalogs": [
    {
      "catalog": "BC",
      "channel": "Partner",
      "partner": "Amazon"
    },
    {
      "catalog": "BC",
      "channel": "Partner",
      "partner": "Ebay"
    },
    {
      "catalog": "BC",
      "channel": "Online"
    },
    {
      "catalog": "BC",
      "channel": "Store"
    },
    {
      "catalog": "CC",
      "channel": "Store"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I have only been able to build the last 3 objects.

Notes:

If channel is **Online** or **Store** the object shouldn't have the partner attribute.

For each partner, the channel attribute should be always **Partner**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This spec produces the expected output

### Version which assumes that `bc_` and `cc_` prefixes are dynamic:

Simpler version can be found at the end of this answer.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "new": {
        "*_sku_partner": {      // 1
          "*": {                // 2
            "*": {              // 3
              "@1": {           // 4
                "$1": "partner__&1__&(4,1).partner",              // 5
                "#Partner": "partner__&1__&(4,1).channel",        // 6
                "$(3,1)": "partner__&1__&(4,1).catalogLowerCase"  // 7
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "*_sku_channel": {
          "*": {
            "Partner": null,        // 8
            "*": {
              "@1": {
                "$1": "channel__&1__&(4,1).channel",
                "$(3,1)": "channel__&1__&(4,1).catalogLowerCase"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",            // 9
    "spec": {
      "partner__*": "catalogs[#1]",
      "channel__*": "catalogs[#1]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",  // 10
    "spec": {
      "catalogs": {
        "*": {
          "catalog": "=toUpper(@(1,catalogLowerCase))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",  // 11
    "spec": {
      "catalogs": {
        "*": {
          "catalogLowerCase": null,
          "*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The first operation is the trickiest, I guess:
It creates a dictionary with unique entries, like:

```json
{
  "channel__Online__bc" : {
    "catalogLowerCase" : "bc",
    "channel" : "Online"
  }
  // ...
  "partner__Amazon__bc": {
    "catalogLowerCase": "bc",
    "channer": "Partner",
    "partner": "Amazon"
  }
}
```

from:

```json
// ...
"bc_sku_partner": [
  "Amazon",
  "Ebay"
]
// ...
```

Let's focus on the first entry generated for "Amazon":

Ad. 1. `*_sku_partner` matches `"bc_sku_partner"`. You could also replace the asterisk with the explicit `bc` value and instead of `$(3,1)` in ad. 7 place `#BC`

Ad. 2. Matches the elements of the `["Amazon", ...]` list.

Ad. 3. We are now inside "Amazon" :D

Ad. 4. We go into "Amazon" and reach for it (`@1`). Related docs: [`@` shift wildcard](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L300)

Ad. 5. Looking at the ([`$` wildcard docs](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L215))

> '$' has the same syntax as the '&' wildcard, and can be read as, dereference to get a value, and then use that value as the data to be output.

`$1` goes up one level, grabs the value (`"Amazon"`) and places it under they `"partner__&1__&(4,1).partner:` key.
`"partner__&1__&(4,1)"` for the `"Amazon"` element generates: `"partner__Amazon__bc"`. `&(4,1)` means here:

> Go up 4 levels (we are at "bc_sku_partner") and take the value matched by the asterisk. See: [`&` wildcard docs](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L184)

Ad. 6. Places `"Partner"` string under the `"channel"` key (next to the `"partner": "Amazon"` key-value).

Ad. 7. `$(3,1)` again but here we reach for the `"bc"` matched by the asterisk and place it under the `"catalogLowerCase"` key.

The `"*_sku_channel"` part is quite similar, so I am not going to explain it.
At ad. 8. is the removal of the `"Partner"` entries.

Ad. 9. The second shift operation. It's purpose is to transform the dictionary produced by the 1st shift operation into the list placed under the `"catalogs"` key. [`#` wildcard](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L261) docs may be useful here.

Ad. 10 and 11 replace the `"catalogLowerCase": "bc"` with `"catalog": "BC"`. Same for the similar `"catalogLowerCase"` fields related to the `"Ebay"`, `"Online"` and `"Store"` entries.

Try to apply the operations incrementally, to see the intermediate result. I recommend this website for testing: https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/. It also has a lot of examples.

---

### Edit:

### Other way to do it, if the `bc_` and `cc_` prefixes are not dynamic.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "new": {
        "bc_sku_partner": { // 1
          "*": { // 2
            "*": { // 3
              "@1": { // 4
                "$1": "partner__&1__bc.partner", // 5
                "#Partner": "partner__&1__bc.channel", // 6
                "#BC": "partner__&1__bc.catalog" // 7
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "bc_sku_channel": {
          "*": {
            "Partner": null,
            "*": {
              "@1": {
                "$1": "channel__&1__bc.channel",
                "#BC": "channel__&1__bc.catalog"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "cc_sku_channel": {
          "*": {
            "Partner": null,
            "*": {
              "@1": {
                "$1": "channel__&1__cc.channel",
                "#CC": "channel__&1__cc.catalog"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "partner__*": "catalogs[#1]",
      "channel__*": "catalogs[#1]"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Just a question in Ad. 7. 
With `$(3,1)` I guess means got up 3 levels and match the first *, so it will point to  `"*_sku_partner"` but in Ad.5 is used `&(4,1)` (4 levels).
So is not totally clear to me how nested levels are handled.

Comment: `$(3,1)` is the key and is one level above the value with the `&(4,1)` part. In other words, value is one level *deeper* than the key.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"new\": {" +
    "    \"bc_sku_partner\": [" +
    "      \"Amazon\"," +
    "      \"Ebay\"" +
    "    ]," +
    "    \"bc_sku_channel\": [" +
    "      \"Partner\"," +
    "      \"Online\"," +
    "      \"Store\"" +
    "    ]," +
    "    \"cc_sku_channel\": [" +
    "      \"Store\"" +
    "    ]" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "new" +
    ".entries()" +
    ".unwind(value)" +
    ".[key='bc_sku_partner' | value!='Partner']*" +
    ".map(catalog:key.substr(0,2).upperCase()," +
    "     channel:if([key='bc_sku_partner'],'Partner',value)," +
    "     partner:if([key='bc_sku_partner'],value))" +
    ".toObject('catalogs')");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "catalogs" : [ {
    "catalog" : "BC",
    "channel" : "Partner",
    "partner" : "Amazon"
  }, {
    "catalog" : "BC",
    "channel" : "Partner",
    "partner" : "Ebay"
  }, {
    "catalog" : "BC",
    "channel" : "Online"
  }, {
    "catalog" : "BC",
    "channel" : "Store"
  }, {
    "catalog" : "CC",
    "channel" : "Store"
  } ]
}
```